# Calculate the difference between two timefields

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

Hi i am using third party API to display the  feeds in our site, in that i have fields called `opentime` and `closetime` in db table. The `feed` table is being updated for every 20 seconds .Things working fine, now the problem is with `opentime` and `closetime`. Its giving 3 Hrs time in the future(it might be their server time) from the current time in my server. Say example, if my server current time is 8:00 AM, at the time feed table is being updated the `opentime` as 11:00 AM(3 Hrs from now, sometime its varying). We can't do any changes with `feed` table since the table is updating automatically through API call.

So i want to find out the time difference between these two(`opentime - currenttime`), how can i able to convert the `opentime` into my server time.

I tried the following code in `my-sql` query,

```
TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,-180,FROM_UNIXTIME(opendate) // subtracting 3 hours(180 min) from the opendate.
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Advance thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but if you are trying to work out the time difference between two times, does it really matter what timezone you're dealing with?

Comment: @NickBarrett- We dont know which timezone they are using, but we are using IST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default time zone for MySQL.  This can be set as a default for your MySQL server, or on the fly with each connection.  Something like this:

```
set timezone='your timezone';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 0):

Set timezone for mysql config

```
set timezone='your timezone';
```

Try it

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2012-10-21', NOW()) as diff;
diff=1997
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the MySQL DateTime functions will work directly on that field, since he's storing a Unix timestamp and not a MySQL temporal value.